# Can I maintain a list of tuples, (timestamps, ids), partially sorted in less than linear time?

Tags: python

The constraints are:

- input is a stream of tuples (timestamp, ids)
- ids are not universally unique so duplicates may come in from stream randomly
- timestamps are not unique either and are also random
- output must be a list of length k where k is small (around 50) and each item within the list is a tuple of (timestamp, ids). ids in the return list must be unique to other ids in the list and timestamps must be the newest 50 from input stream.

My thoughts were to use a map and a heap but any solution I come up with uses linear time.

Comment: What is the type of `ids`?

Comment: Assuming the "compare" operation takes constant time, a binary search tree would get you logarithmic insertion and access, which is better than linear.

Comment: are you reading it from CSV file?  from where the data is coming?

Comment: the ids are string and the data is coming from a black box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort() function, i've taken a simple code from https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort

```
# take second element for sort
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]

# random list
random = [(2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 3)]

# sort list with key
random.sort(key=takeSecond)

# print list
print('Sorted list:', random)

Output

Sorted list: [(4, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4)]
```

and for the duplicatad ids, you can use the map() funcition while inserting the tuples in the list.